# Use rows values from a pandas dataframe as new columns label

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I have a pandas dataframe it's possible to get values from a row and use it as a label for a new column?

I have something like this:

```
| Team| DateTime| Score
| Red| 2021/03/19 | 5
| Red| 2021/03/20 | 10
| Blue| 2022/04/10 | 20
```

I would like to write this data on a new dataframe that has:

**Team Column**

**Year/Month SumScore Column**

So I would have  a row per team with multiple new columns for a month in a year that contains the sum of the score for a specific month.
It should be like this:

| Team | 2021/03 | 2022/04 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Red | 15 | 0 |
| Blue | 0 | 20 |

The date format time is YYYY/MM/DD

I hope I was clear

Comment: create an example of what you want, it is not clear if you want multiindex or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) which allows us to

> Compute a simple cross tabulation of two (or more) factors

Below I've changed `df['DateTime']` to contain `year/month` only.

```
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime']).dt.strftime('%Y/%m')
pd.crosstab(
    df['Team'],
    df['DateTime'],
    values=df['Score'],
    aggfunc='sum'
).fillna(0)
```

If you don't want multiple levels in the index, just use the method call `reset_index` on your crosstab and then drop `DateTime`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
df = (df.assign(YM=df['DateTime'].str.rsplit('/', 1).str[0])
      .pivot_table(index='Team', columns='YM', values='Score', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
      .reset_index())
```

```
print(df)

YM  Team  2021/03  2022/04
0   Blue        0       20
1    Red       15        0
```